# Where is the best place to store the key for encryption a password in keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, security, encryption

I want to implement a second security, because when the phone is jail broken the keychain is vulnerable and I don’t want my passwords to be secure only by the keychain. That’s why I want to encrypt the password by me before save the in the keychain.

The reason I want to encrypt it is because the server for login accepts a plain text password not hashed. I had the idea to have a rout for encrypting and when the user logins for first time, the password is send as a plain text and after that encrypted.

The encryption to happens on the backend and the backend can decrypt it. Is this a good idea, because when the user changes his/her password he/she needs to enter the old one as a plain text and I call the encryption rout on which I sends the password. It is responding me with an encrypted one of it and I am
comparing them. So in the keychain is only the encrypted one.

Is there a better way if it is where to store the key if I am encrypting the password on the device? If it is a static hard-coded field it is not OK. If it is in the keychain too, and on the server it is possible to have a different encryption key for every user. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Any encryption key you have on the device will be vulnerable to the same attack that makes the keychain vulnerable. Your sever should store a salted hash of the password. You would also store the salted hash in the keychain. It should never be possible to decrypt the password.  Presumably the person who is jail breaking the device and access the keychain is the owner of the device and they know the password anyway. A 3rd party can't attack the keychain as long as the owner has set a passcode.

Comment: And about the encryption routes, what you think or about the static hard coded field. The other think is that I added the check for jailbreaked phone which I found in the internet but as I read this is happening harder and harder to detect.

Comment: @Paulw11 but if I store the hash the hacker can use this hash to login, where is the security here

Comment: I am not sure why you are worried about jail breaking; if the user jailbreaks their phone, what does it matter?  They already know the password. Really you need your backend to change; you should never need to send it the clear text password. Just send it the salted hash during user sign up.  Even for password change you just need to send the old salted hash and the new salted hash. Any encryption on device is vulnerable which is why you use hashing,  not encryption.

Comment: The security is the passcode on the device. If you don't trust the security of the device, don't store anything.  If you store an encrypted password then the attacker can just decrypt the password (because your app contains the code required to decrypt the password) and now they have the clear text password that the user may have used on another app/site.

Comment: I mean the user is using Face ID and if it successes or Touch ID am getting the password from keychain and sending it, when the password is already hashed and salted and I send it, it will success to and if the attacker gets this password hashed and encrypted from keychain and sends it, he will successes to

Comment: Right, but how does the attacker get the password from the keychain?  Let's say they steal the device and then wanT to jaikbreak it. They have to reboot the device, which will lock the keychain until it gets the passcode. If you are worried that someone has jailbroken their device already and maybe has malware, well, isn't that their problem? They are taking a risk by jaikbreaking. Also [this](https://xkcd.com/538/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer to this question, as the threat vector is too broad. You want to protect some secret information even if the device security is compromised (someone other that the user of the phone has jailbroken / hacked it). The best information about this can be found in the article *[Secret Management on iOS](https://nshipster.com/secrets/)*.

TL;DR: “Don’t (but if you must, obfuscation wouldn’t hurt).”